# Huawei Ads, onAdClosed is not called

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I'm trying to integrate the interstitial ad from Huawei Ads, when I click on **(X)** or **back button** to close the ad, for some reason the `Toast` inside `onAdClosed` method is not showing.

```
  huaweiInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this);
  huaweiInterstitialAd.setAdId("teste9ih9j0rc3");

 private void showHuaweiInterstitial() {
        if (huaweiInterstitialAd != null && huaweiInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            huaweiInterstitialAd.show(MainActivity.this);
        }
    }

public void loadHuaweiInterstitialAd() {
    huaweiInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            super.onAdLoaded();
            showHuaweiInterstitial();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailed(int errorCode) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Ad load failed with error code: " + errorCode);
        }


        @Override
        public void onAdLeave() {
            super.onAdLeave();
            Log.d(TAG, "onAdLeave");
        }


        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            super.onAdClosed();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ad Closed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClicked() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onAdClicked");
            super.onAdClicked();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onAdOpened");
            super.onAdOpened();
        }
    });
    AdParam adParam = new AdParam.Builder().build();
    huaweiInterstitialAd.loadAd(adParam);
}
```

The problem only occurs if you use:

```
 implementation 'com.huawei.hms:ads:3.4.46.300'
```

But everything works fine with :

```
  implementation 'com.huawei.hms:ads-lite:13.4.46.300'
```

Comment: hi@Mouaad, Sorry we did not reproduce your issue. Could you pls provide the build.gradle file in your app directory for us to confirm, also may i know what was your test device model?

Comment: @shirley Thank you for your comment, I've solved the issue by using a separate thread inside `onAdClosed` method, I would like to use Huawei Ads, but the SDK contains a lot of extra permissions (Bluetooth, QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES, GET_TASK, GET_INSTALLED_APPS...) this will definitely make trouble with Google Play

Comment: Glad the problem has been resolved. And the ads kit sdk does require the permissions you say, but the bluetooth permissions are not. 

Comment: @shirley Not the Bluetooth only, it has the Calendar read and write permissions, I can't ask the user to allow all these permissions, and also too many permissions = too many issues with Google Play, ps : I'm not talking about the LITE SDK, I talk about the full SDK